# Compute $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln{\cos{x}}}{e^{2x^2}-\cos{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

This should be done without using L'Hopital's rule and without using the $\sec(x)$ and $\csc{x}$ functions. I tried substituting $t=\cos{x}\rightarrow x=\arccos{t}$ and obtain

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln{(1+t)}}{e^{2\arccos^2(t)}-t},$$

Dividing nominator and denominator by $t$ I get

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{\ln{t}}{t}}{\frac{e^{2\arccos^2(t)}}{t}-1}$$

But this gives division by zero. I also tried multilying both sides by $t/t$ but then I get multiplication by zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln{\cos{x}}}{e^{2x^2}-\cos{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln{(1+\cos{x}-1)}}{(\cos{x}-1)\cdot\frac{e^{2x^2}-1+1-\cos{x}}{2x^2}\cdot\frac{2x^2}{\cos{x}-1}}=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{4}\right)\cdot(-4)}=-\frac{1}{5}$$

I used the following.
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1,$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$$ and
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}=1.$$

Comment: First things first: 1) How on earth did you just come up with that within minutes? 2) Can you elaborate on the steps? I see that you added and subtracted one in the logarithm, but then?

Comment: It's $e^{2x^2}$.

Comment: @Parseval I solved already one or maybe two problems in math an I can see an idea quickly enough. I added something. See now.

Comment: @Parseval: This is a fairly standard procedure for evaluation of limits (and my preferred approach). It makes use of the standard limit formulas (the three limits at the end of this answer belong to this category) and the laws of algebra of limits. You have to manipulate the given expression in order to make use of the standard limits.